# Internet Explorer p3p iframe and trird party cookies

Tags: php, iframe, p3p

This problem is driving me crazy.

I have pages on my site that load a affiliate page in an iframe.  I have set up a p3p policy and everything validates.

http://validator.w3.org/p3p/20020128/p3p.pl?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fallbuys.ca%2Fdeal%2F167%2F

My header looks good...

```
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 08 Feb 2011 01:56:20 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Content-Length: 4329
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Tue, 08 Feb 2011 01:56:21 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.38.245.230:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Link: ; rel="P3Pv1"
Link: <../../style.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
P3P: policyref="http://allbuys.ca/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa CONa OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV DEM STA"
Title: Allbuys.ca - Your City, Why Not Save?
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
```

I can not get rid of the red privacy eye in IE...?..?

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need the third party site to set up the P3P policy on their end.